# Get dimensions of objects from a image

Tags: matlab

There is an image in which I want to get the actual size (real life length) of an object that is present in it. However, it is only known the dimension of another object present in the image. How can I associate a length value to this object (that i know it's length) and get the size of the other object?

Example: There is an image with two objects, an apple and a book. The apple width is 2 inches. Knowing this, how wide is the book?

Is it possible to acquire that with MatLab?
@edit - Here is an image as an example
[Building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKkhz.png)

Comment: You could have an approximation if the measure for both objects is in the same plane and that plane is perpendicular to the camera.  You could then count the pixels for each measure and use rule of three. Or are you thinking in something more complex?

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do, but it needs to be automatic. I'm trying to write a code that identifies the object and shows it's length. Not sure if matlab is the best way to do it though.

Comment: Then your problem is not getting the object dimension (that will be the easy part, you will do it by counting pixels). Your problem is image recognition. That's pretty complex unless there are some simplifications for the input images (for instance: there are just 2 objects in each image, you are always comparing to the same object and there's a green background). You should specify how the input images are going to be.

Comment: Please add an example of the real image that you are trying to analyze as it will help in giving you the best options for that specific example.

Comment: If the apple and book aren't necessarily the same distance from the camera this problem is ill posed, i.e. it can't be solved geometrically. Even if they are and the image hasn't been corrected for distortion then again the problem is ill posed.

Comment: I put an image up there as an example (@edit), i need to be able to get the distance from one floor to the other.

Answer (score 0):

To recognize floors you can use one of many line detection algorithms. Not sure but Hough transform can be sufficient, for details please see documentation on houghlines and vast number of questions on SO. After you extracted the lines you should make sure they are parallel, if not, you'll need to remove perspective distortion (another popular topic). Finally calculate distances between now-parallel lines in pixels and multiply by a known scale.

In the image it is not shown what you plan using as scale bar. Should the "unit object" be recognized automatically or you'll mark it manually? Sorry, I'm unable to comment on the question